# How to target a specific Wikipedia table element for bs4 scrape?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: here is what I'm trying to target with BeautifulSoup]

Here is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
my_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%9320_Wuhan_coronavirus_outbreak'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
page_soup.tbody.tr?
```

I'm trying to target this table element, but it is not unique. How can I capture this nested element called "< td style...< b"?

I could do page_soup.h1 to grab all the h1 tag stuff, but there's many repeated tags here, and I could use some help. I did UTFSE but am still confused. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try something like this:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%9320_Wuhan_coronavirus_outbreak'
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
resp = requests.get(url)


soup = bs(resp.text,'lxml')

tabs = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
tot = tabs.find_all('tr',{'style':'vertical-align:top'})
for t in tot:    
    rows = t.find_all('td',style=None)
    for r in rows:
        if r.text.strip() == "Total":
            print(m.nextSibling.text)
```

The idea behind it is that the target number `2903` is located after a row with the (stripped) 
 text `Total`. The word `Total` is in a `td` tag which has no `style` attribute. We locate that tag, and the target number is in the text of its immediate sibling.

Output:

> 2,903

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic. How did you learn to do this? Great stuff.

Comment: @MattNewtonian - It took a while... Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to find the text `total` and then `find_next('b')`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
my_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%9320_Wuhan_coronavirus_outbreak'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")
my_table = page_soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
item=my_table.find('b',text=re.compile('Total')).find_next('b').text
print(item)
```

**Output**:

```
2,903
```